# VLC won't play music

Tags: music, vlc

I am currently running Ubuntu 13.04.  I have used VLC fine for years, but it suddenly stopped working.  I believe it was working when I updated to 13.04.  A little bit ago, I enabled raring-proposed, and I'm not sure if that was the cause of the issue or not (I usually listen to music on Pandora, so I didn't notice exactly when the issue started).

MP3s don't work.  OGG music files don't work.  However, both of those work in Rhythmbox.  Also, watching MKV video files works in VLC.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue was, but resetting my VLC preferences (per the advice at http://www.videolan.org/support/faq.html) fixed things.